# Typescript default export

Tags: javascript, typescript

I just started taking a look at Typescript and have an issue when playing around.
I want to write a library to manage a general tree structure and just doing some very basic tests to see how TS works.

Start of the simple setup with 3 files:

- GForest.ts
- GTree.ts
- GNode.ts

Currently, GForest.ts:

```
import * as Immutable   from "immutable"; 
import GTree            from "./GTree"; 

export default class Forest{ 
    public static createTree(){ 
        let tree = new GTree(); 
    } 
}
```

GTree.ts:

```
export default class GTree{ 
    constructor(){ 
        console.log("Tree constructed"); 
    } 

    public static createNode(){ 

    } 
}
```

I created a simple test.js file to call the library (compiled TS to ES5):

```
var GForest = require("./build/GForest"); 

console.log(GForest);
```

When running

```
> node test
```

The output is:

I don't understand why the result is:

```
{ default: { [Function: Forest] createTree: [Function] } }
```

Why is there an object with `default` as key and how do I change this to achieve desired behaviour?

Because of this, I'm unable to just call:

```
GForest.createTree();
```

(I want to expose the creation of a tree through a static factory) 
Any help?

Comment: why do you use `var GForest = require("./build/GForest"); ` inside `test.js` instead of `import` and then compiling the file to js?

Comment: @Maximus I just run test.js as a simple node script. Not sure why I would want to write import, then compile for this (?).

Comment: Never mind, please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use the ES6 `default` export

I quote the article [ES6 In Depth: Modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) from Mozilla:

> If you’d like your own ES6 module to have a default export, that’s easy to do. There’s nothing magic about a default export; it’s just like any other export, except it’s named `"default"`.

In your `test.js` file, the "default" feature is inelegant because you want to consume the ES6 `default` export from an ES5 syntax. I suggest to use the ES6 syntax with the help of TypeScript:

```
// test.ts
import GForest from "./build/GForest";
console.log(GForest); // { [Function: Forest] createTree: [Function] }
```

This code is compiled to:

```
var GForest_1 = require("./build/GForest"); 
console.log(GForest_1.default);
```

## Directly export a class

In TypeScript, you can directly export a member with the non-standard syntax `export =`.

Example:

```
// GForest.ts
import * as Immutable   from "immutable"; 
import GTree            from "./GTree"; 

class Forest{ 
    public static createTree(){ 
        let tree = new GTree(); 
    } 
}
export = Forest;
```

Then, use it with a code ES3/5:

```
// test.js
let GForest = require("./build/GForest");
console.log(GForest); // { [Function: Forest] createTree: [Function] }
```

... or, in TypeScript:

```
// test.ts
import GForest = require("./build/GForest");
console.log(GForest); // { [Function: Forest] createTree: [Function] }
```

See [the documentation on `export =` here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require).

Comment: Because I happen to write the lib in TS, doesn't mean that the consumer should? Test.js is just a representation of an arbitrary consumer and I prefer not to make it an opinionated lib.

Comment: @KimGysen OK, I think I understand what you need. I edited.

Comment: That's what I need... Still unclear to me why they promote the use of default export though (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). Doesn't seem to add any benefit.

Comment: @KimGysen Maybe because it is the way promoted by the standard ES6?

Comment: @Maximus My bad! I forgot to remove the first `export`. I edited.

Comment: @Paleo, yeah, thanks, I figured that out) good answer, upvoted

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there an object with default as key and how do I change this to
>   achieve desired behaviour?

That's because it is what is exported from compiled `GForest.js`:

```
"use strict";
var GTree_1 = require("./GTree");
var Forest = (function () {
    function Forest() {
    }
    Forest.createTree = function () {
        var tree = new GTree_1["default"]();
    };
    return Forest;
}());
exports.__esModule = true;
exports["default"] = Forest;
```

You need to use `.default` to refer to the constructor:

```
var GForest = require("./build/GForest").default;
```

Typescript uses `es6` module syntax which can export multiple modules. This code is then compiled into `commonjs` `es5` module syntax. Typescript compiler uses `properties` on `exports` object to map multiple exports defined on `es6` module syntax. And `default` is just like any other `named` export.

Comment: Yes of course, but why does it do that? Isn't `export default class Forest` correct syntax in TS to behave as a module; why does it have to add the default property? If I want to expose this as a library, the `default` just makes it look ugly...

Comment: @KimGysen, updated. What module system do your library consumers will use?

Comment: Perhaps it's me, but I find this awkward. In the article: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html, section `Guidance for structuring modules`, they say: `If you’re only exporting a single class or function, use export default`. Yet it comes with the cost of the `default`property that makes the import clunky for commonjs users. However if I don't, then it is required to use braces `import {GForest} etc`. I'm looking for a way to export as default, and just import without unnecessary side-effects.

Comment: @KimGysen, you're referring to the documentation of TypeScript, however you use JS `es5`